# Access Query parameters in Spring cloud function + AWS Lamba + API gateway

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, spring-cloud-function

I am using Spring cloud function with AWS Lambda and API Gateway.

Below is my function:

```
 @Bean
        public Function<String, User> testFunction() {
            return (input) -> {
                return new User(1, input);
            };
```

Also, I have specified the handler in AWS Lambda console as below:
org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.FunctionInvoker::handleRequest

If I send a Request with string body, it is successfully able to collect the input.

But I do not understand, how do I access the request query parameters inside the function?
Something like this:
https://[apigateway].aws.com/[path]?param1=value

Can someone guide me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a good solution?

Comment: Yes, use Message<POJO> as input type for your function. Then you get path and query params as part of the Message object.